# Laravel Thumbnail Can't read Original Image

Tags: laravel-5, thumbnails

I am trying to store user info including a pic in Laravel 5.3. Here is the relevant code:

```
if ( isset($request->image) )
            {$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/users');}

        $user = User::find($request->id);
        if (isset($path))
            {$user->image = $path;}
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->active = $request->active;
        $user->admin = $request->admin;
        $user->address = $request->address;
        $user->country_id = $request->country_id;
        if ($request->ageverified = 1)
            {$user->ageverified = 1;}
        if ($request->verifieddate <> '')
        {$user->verifieddate = $request->verifieddate;}
        $user->verify_notes = $request->verify_notes;
        $user->publisher = $request->publisher;
        $user->paypal = $request->paypal;
        $user->proname = $request->proname;

        if (isset($path)) {
            $file = Storage::url($path);
            $tpath = basename($path);
            Image::make($path)->resize(100,
                100)->save('public/users/thumbs/'.tpath);
            $user->thumbnail = $tpath;

        }

        $user->save();
```

The image is stored OK but when I get to making the thumbnail I am getting:

```
NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302: Image source not readable
```

I have tried everything but am really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this out in a laracast forum - see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/53-image-source-not-readable